# Custom Cell.accessoryView of UITableView showing only first row in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Hello i need to add custom cell accessoryView in my app.

Here is my code for custom cellAccessorView.

```
self.viewOfAccessory = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 55)];
self.lblDay.text = @"Monday";
[self.viewOfAccessory addSubview:self.lblDay];
cell.accessoryView = self.viewOfAccessory;
```

However it showing only in first row. Not in every row of tableView.

I want to do like following pic.

[image]

How can i do it?

Comment: What is the method from which you took these four lines?

Comment: I wrote above code in cellForRowAtIndexPath of UITableView bro.

Comment: It's strange that you set `viewOfAccessory` and `self.lblDay.text` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: these should be set only once at initialization. Only `cell.accessoryView` needs to be set inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and it should be set unconditionally (i.e. not only when "recycled" `cell` returns a `nil`).

Comment: paste here whole cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: i added pic that i want to do like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view can only be added in one place. You are using the `self.viewOfAccessory` property to define what you want shown and then trying to add it to all of your cells. However, `self.viewOfAccessory` will only show up in one place. If you add it somewhere else (i.e. another row) it will just be moved. You need to be creating separate views and adding them to each cell.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem might be because you're calling elements as part of "self" and then adding them again in "self" (which should be the tableViewController), try this:

```
UIView* viewOfAccessory = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 55)];
//Get the text from lblDay label, check if the "self." is necessary
self.lblDay.text = @"Monday"; //Not sure about this line since I don't have the whole code
[viewOfAccessory addSubview: lblDay];
cell.accessoryView = viewOfAccessory;
```